# Design a saturated sum with window functions

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have, in a pyspark dataframe, a column with values 1, -1 and 0, representing the events "startup", "shutdown" and "other" of an engine. I want to build a column with the state of the engine, with 1 when the engine is on and 0 when it's off, something like:

```
+---+-----+-----+
|seq|event|state|
+---+-----+-----+
| 1 |   1 |   1 |
| 2 |   0 |   1 |
| 3 |  -1 |   0 |
| 4 |   0 |   0 |
| 5 |   0 |   0 |
| 6 |   1 |   1 |
| 7 |  -1 |   0 |
+---+-----+-----+
```

If 1s and -1s are always alternated, this can easily be done with a window function such as

```
sum('event').over(Window.orderBy('seq'))
```

It can happen, though, that I have some spurious 1s or -1s, which I want to ignore if I am already in state 1 or 0, respectively. I want thus to be able to do something like:

```
+---+-----+-----+
|seq|event|state|
+---+-----+-----+
| 1 |   1 |   1 |
| 2 |   0 |   1 |
| 3 |   1 |   1 |
| 4 |  -1 |   0 |
| 5 |   0 |   0 |
| 6 |  -1 |   0 |
| 7 |   1 |   1 |
+---+-----+-----+
```

That would require a "saturated" sum function that never goes above 1 or below 0, or some other approach which I am not able to imagine at the moment.

Does somebody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result using the last function to fill-forwards the most recent state-change.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = (spark.createDataFrame([
        (1, 1),
        (2, 0),
        (3, -1),
        (4, 0)
    ], ["seq", "event"]))

w = Window.orderBy('seq')

#replace zeros with nulls so they can be ignored easily.
df = df.withColumn('helperCol',F.when(df.event != 0,df.event))

#fill statechanges forward in a new column.
df = df.withColumn('state',F.last(df.helperCol,ignorenulls=True).over(w))

#replace -1 values with 0
df = df.replace(-1,0,['state'])

df.show()
```

This produces:

```
+---+-----+---------+-----+
|seq|event|helperCol|state|
+---+-----+---------+-----+
|  1|    1|        1|    1|
|  2|    0|     null|    1|
|  3|   -1|       -1|    0|
|  4|    0|     null|    0|
+---+-----+---------+-----+
```

`helperCol` need not be added to the dataframe, I have only included it to make the process more readable.